# How to add a separating line between rows of a table with "border-collapse: separate"?

Tags: html, css

I want to have a separating line under each row when using `border-collapse: separate;`.
But using `border-bottom` on the `tr` doesn't work when `border-collapse` is set to `separate`, so I tried giving `border-bottom` to the `td`, however - it has space between each column:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 5px 0;
}

th {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}

td {
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Header 1</th>
    <th>Header 2</th>
    <th>Header 3</th>
    <th>Header 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How to achieve a full-line border without spaces? Something like that:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 5px 0;
}

th {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}

tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Header 1</th>
    <th>Header 2</th>
    <th>Header 3</th>
    <th>Header 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>Some Data</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Is there another reason for having the border-spacing at 5px

Answer (score 0):

The border-spacing property adds space between cells in a table when border-collapse is set to separate.
It defines the distance between the borders of adjacent cells, both horizontally and vertically.
Hence, if you want to remove the horizontal space between your cells you would need to set

```
border-spacing: 0;
```